# Query output differs from the expected output

Tags: mysql, count

Below query is doing what I need:

```
SELECT assign.from_uid, assign.aid, assign.message, curriculum.asset, 
       curriculum.title, curriculum.description 
FROM assignment assign 
INNER JOIN curriculum_topics_assets curriculum 
   ON assign.nid = curriculum.asset 
WHERE assign.to_uid = 13 AND assign.status = 1 
GROUP BY assign.from_uid, assign.to_uid, assign.nid 
ORDER BY assign.created DESC
```

Now I need to get the total count of rows of the result. For example if it is displaying 5 rows the o/p should be like My expected o/p. The query I tried is given below.

```
SELECT count(description) FROM assignment assign 
INNER JOIN curriculum_topics_assets curriculum ON assign.nid = curriculum.asset 
WHERE assign.to_uid = 13 AND assign.status = 1 
GROUP BY assign.from_uid, assign.to_uid, assign.nid 
ORDER BY assign.created DESC
```

**My expected o/p:**

```
count(*)
---------
5
```

**My current o/p:**

```
count(*)
---------
6
2
5
6
6
```

Comment: @@Harry Joy: please see the edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to

- place your initial `GROUP BY` query in a subselect
- select the amount of rows retrieved from this subselect

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
          SELECT  assign.from_uid 
          FROM    assignment assign 
                  INNER JOIN curriculum_topics_assets curriculum ON assign.nid = curriculum.asset 
          WHERE   assign.to_uid = 13 
                  AND assign.status = 1 
          GROUP BY 
                  assign.from_uid
                  , assign.to_uid
                  , assign.nid 
       ) q
```

#### Edit - why doesn't the original query return the results required

It did already prepared what was needed to *get* the correct result

1. Your query without grouping returns a resultset of 25 records (6+2+5+6+6)
2. From these 25 records, you have 5 unique combinations of `from_uid, to_uid, nid`

Now you don't want to count how many records each combination has (as you did in your example) but how many unique *(distinct anyone?)* combinations there are.

One solution to this is the subselect I presented but following equivalent statement using a `DISTINCT` clause might be more comprehensive.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    (
          SELECT  DISTINCT assign.from_uid
                  , assign.to_uid
                  , assign.nid
          FROM    assignment assign 
                  INNER JOIN curriculum_topics_assets curriculum ON assign.nid = curriculum.asset 
          WHERE   assign.to_uid = 13 
                  AND assign.status = 1 
        ) q
```

*Note that my personal preference goes to the `GROUP BY` solution.*

Comment: @@leiven: it's working great.. :-).. One more favour.. Why count(*) doesn't work ?

Comment: @Fero - The `COUNT(*)` in my example is no problem and I don't see one in your question? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @Lieven: He means why his second query does not work (does not give same result as yours).

Comment: @ypercube - <slap forehead> I see. I'll edit the answer to try to clear that up.

Comment: @Fero - I have added some additional explanation trying to clear things up.

Comment: Your explanation is tooooooooo good and understandable.. Thanks a lot for ur help

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of rows for a query do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as RowCount FROM (--insert other query here--) s
```

In you example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as RowCount FROM (SELECT a.from_uid
  FROM assignment a 
  INNER JOIN curriculum_topics_assets c ON a.nid = c.asset 
  WHERE a.to_uid = 13 
    AND a.status = 1 
  GROUP BY a.from_uid, a.to_uid, a.nid 
  ) s
```

Note that I the dropped the stuff that has no effect on the number of rows to make the query run slightly faster.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `COUNT(*)` instead of `count(description)`. Look at: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: I did that... But the o/p is same for both COUNT(*) instead of count(description)